# Terraform vSphere Customize Operating System

Tags: terraform

Been looking at the Terraform vSphere Provider Documentation with regards to deploying Windows Servers Using Custom OS Guest Settings: All i can see from it's site is the following.

```
customize {
  linux_options / windows_option{
    host_name = "terraform-test"
    domain    = "test.internal"
  }
```

The Above creates a new Customs Guest Setting, What i'm looking for is to deploy using one that is already configured.

[OS Custom Guest Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m2ZD.png)

```
        disk {
        label            = "${var.Variable_VM_Name}_disk0"
        size             = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size}"
        eagerly_scrub    = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.eagerly_scrub}"
        thin_provisioned = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned}"
        }

        clone {
        template_uuid = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id}"
      }
     customize {
  windows_option{ TO-DO }

    }
```